# using CSV's date in powerbi

Tags: date, powerbi, data-visualization, metadata, powerbi-desktop

I'm currently building a dashboard with powerbi and several CSV as sources.

Those CSV will have regular updates and i want to get a visualisation with the date of the last source update (for every CSV)

Is there a way to use the metadata csv file in powerbi to visualise it ?

Or a better way to get what i'm seeking for ?

Regards,

I tried the solution proposed:

[image]

[image]

Which mean the function is not well orthographied , any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Folder.Files` with appropriate filters, to get to file metadata.

It's simple enough to use a function to get the data you want:

*fnFileData:*

```
(FullFilename as text, OutputType as text) =>
let
    Filepath = Text.BeforeDelimiter(FullFilename, "\", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}) & "\",
    Filename = Text.AfterDelimiter(FullFilename, "\", {0, RelativePosition.FromEnd}),
    Filtered = Table.SelectRows(Folder.Files(Filepath), each [Folder Path] = Filepath and [Name] = Filename),
    Filedata = Table.TransformColumnNames(Filtered, Text.Lower),
    Output = Table.Column(Filedata,Text.Lower(OutputType)){0}
in
    Output
```

In this case, if you want the Date Modified, then invoke as

```
= fnFileData("C:\MyPath\MyFile.txt", "Date Modified")
```

Comment: Hello,

thanks for your answer,

I tried your solution but i have an error message, i put the screenshot on the initial ask for more clarity

Comment: Did you add my code into another separate query, and name that query "fnFileData" ?

Comment: No , my bad, it was a simple personnalised column, should i write it this way:

let
    fnFileData("C:\MyPath\MyFile.txt", "Date Modified")

or with the code you write earlier ?